# Find specific text and delete three rows above it

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with my macros, and I thought that I'd ask the macro pros on here again for some assistance.

I need help locating certain text in a row and deleting three rows above it, unlooped. 
This is what I've been using and it's not working. 
[Image of: What I need deleted and the required end result. Also the Macros that I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNyGL.jpg)

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim x
For x = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row To ActiveCell.Row Step -1
    If Cells(x, 1) = "TOT" Then 
        Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete      
        Cells(x - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete  
        Cells(x - 2, 1).EntireRow.Delete  
        Cells(x - 3, 1).EntireRow.Delete  
End If

End Sub
```

I've also looked around online for other solutions to this common problem, but nothing worked for me. I need for this macro to be usable in any page of the Excel Work book.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Hi Bernie, you are amazing! This worked like a charm and it's even sort of easy for a newbie like me to understand what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the below edit should help

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim xRow As Integer
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = "TOT"
' Assuming Total is in column C as your picture shows, but you can configure to search anywhere

xRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$C1:C" & xRow).Select

Selection.Find(What:=strSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0).Row).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, if this works for you, I hate to ask but, can you +1.  Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why to make a loop? Why not only select the things auto?

```
Sub Delete_Rows()
    Const WordToLook = "TOT"
    Dim RowWord As Long
    RowWord = Columns(3).Find(WordToLook, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    Rows(RowWord - 3 & ":" & RowWord - 1).Delete
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Don't really appreciate being called a dummy though.

Comment: Ohh lol, I didn't meant it to offend you! I tend to use "dummy" to stand for "dummy data" -simulate that there's data in the sheet- not for you!

Comment: Oh ok. Yea, can be confusing. Thanks for the help above.

Answer (score 0):

This will find "TOT" anywhere in the sheet and delete 3 rows above it.

```
Sub Delete()
Dim find As String: find = "TOT"
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.find(What:=find, After:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  rng.EntireRow.Delete
  rng.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete
  rng.Offset(-2).EntireRow.Delete
  rng.Offset(-3).EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, NuWin!

Comment: Your welcome, if this was the solution you were looking for then mark it as the answer.

Comment: I actually need this to work on any and all the worksheets in the excel file, and this code unfortunately only works for Sheet1.